# Updating row in ResultSet generates error: 'Value conflicts occurs'

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

Our company wrote a rather complex program to transfer data from one database to another. Data that is supposed to be transferred is marked by a '1' (String/Varchar2) in a certain column.
I can't explain why this is not simply a numerical or boolean field. I guess it's a historic remnant.

The `ResultSet` is created like this:

```
Statement stmt = conn.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
ResultSet extractedData = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
```

If something was found extract it to a file:

```
if (extractedData.next()) {
    writeDataToFile(extractedData)
}
```

The simplified writing method looks like this:

```
private void writeDataToFile(ResultSet extractedData) {

    extractedData.beforeFirst(); // because of the next() we called before
    writeLines(extractedData);

}
```

In `writeLines()` we are iterating through the whole `ResultSet` and write it to a file.

After we are done with that we can mark the data as transferred by setting the value in the column to '0'. We cannot do it earlier in case an exception occurs.

```
extractedData.beforeFirst();
while (extractedData.next()) {      
    extractedData.updateString(updateColumn, "0");
    extractedData.updateRow();
}
```

We suspect that `updateRow()` causes the `SQLException` with the message 'Value conflicts occurs'

It happens very rarely. Millions of records are extracted like this every month and only approximately 2 of them throw this error.

Does anybody have a clue what could cause this?

Comment: Do you have the entire errormessage + stacktrace?

Comment: @MarkRotteveel 'Value conflicts occurs' is the `ex.getMessage()`. I don't have the entire stacktrace because we are catching the exception and only log the message.

Comment: I guess it is an Oracle error message (ORA-17085). But google results are very sparse on that one.

Comment: I'd strongly suggest that moving on you also log stacktraces, you never know what kind of info you can glean from where the exception was thrown. Have you tried things like updating to the latest driver? Another thing it could be is a concurrent transaction that also updated the value (or something else in the row), but that is just a guess; a quick google doesn't give any helpful information.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I found a record that was inserted exactly at the time the error was logged but new inserts should only lock the current record not the whole table or other records. Is the `ResultSet` maybe influenced by this?

Comment: I don't know for sure; I don't use Oracle directly, so I don't know all ins and outs of the driver and Oracle. As the statement is `TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE`, I wouldn't expect it to be affected by new records.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ResultSet not establish any lock on table row. And another process can change it. Exception will appear when something happens with rowid in oracle.
How to replicate this behaviour.

```
create table example1 (id number, value varchar2(10));
insert into example1 values(1,'a');
insert into example1 values(2,'b');
insert into example1 values(3,'c');
insert into example1 values(4,'d');
insert into example1 values(5,'e');
commit;
```

And java APP. deleteRow - open new oracle session and delete row from table.

```
public class Updatable {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException, Exception {
        Connection conn = ConnectionDefinition.getOracleConnection();
        Statement  createStatement = conn.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
        ResultSet  executeQuery = createStatement.executeQuery("select id, value from example1");       
        while (executeQuery.next()) {               
            int id = executeQuery.getInt("id");
            System.out.println("id " + executeQuery.getString("id") + " value " + executeQuery.getString("value"));
            if (id == 3) {            
                deleteRow();
                Thread.sleep(5000);
                executeQuery.updateString("VALUE", "new value");
                executeQuery.updateRow();
            }
        }
        conn.close();
    }
    public static void deleteRow(){        
        Runnable r = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Connection conn = ConnectionDefinition.getOracleConnection();
                    PreparedStatement st = conn.prepareStatement("delete from example1 where id = 3");                    
                    st.execute();
                    st.close();
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                   ex.getStackTrace();
                }
            }
        };
        Thread  th = new Thread(r);
        th.start();
    }
}
```

To avoid such conflicts, use the Oracle FOR UPDATE feature when running the query. 
`ResultSet  executeQuery = createStatement.executeQuery("select id, value from example1 for update");`

Comment: thanks. is the rowid also affected when a different process inserts a new record? or only on deletions?

Comment: meh, nevermind. just found out that some users are actually able to delete records. They create a record and find out that they entered rubbish and delete it while our program extracts the data. Since we are not  blocking the row it runs into an exception. Thanks alot.